# Applet not working on JRE 6u25

Tags: java, applet, snmp

I have an applet that is connecting to a device and gets its paramaters throgh SNMP protocol. it is working fine on JRE 6u20, but after updating JRE to 6u25 its not working well.

On 6u20 retrieving of device paramteres tooks a few seconds, but on 6u25 it tooks much more and finally most of paramters are not retrieved.

There is a SwingWorker for reading each paramater and I use this [Java SNMP Package](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/snmp/).

What is the diffrence between these versions of JRE? how to find out what makes the problem?

Comment: An obvious question perhaps, but have you checked the bug database?

Comment: @Andrew: I tried 6u24 and 6u23 versions and they are not working as 6u25, no I have not checked the bug database. I'll check it now.

Comment: You should post your update as an answer, and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I figured it out what was the problem. [Java SNMP Package](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/snmp/) GetRequest is not thread-safe. on JRE 6u20 there was no problem because SwingWorker default thread pool in JRE 6u20 has only one worker thread but in JRE 6u25 the number of worker threads is 10

```
SwingWorker.MAX_WORKER_THREADS = 10;
```

By adding "*synchronized* " keyword to SNMP get request method the problem is solved.

```
synchronized public SNMPVarBindList getMIBEntry(String itemID)
```